# DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior is not found when trying to use DataContractResolver

Tags: wcf

I am trying to use DataContractResolver as an alternative to KnownTypes in WCF.

I have the following code and I've used it before on the server side. But on the client side, the code returns null when trying to find DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior in operation behaviors collection.

```
public override IMyService CreateProxy(Uri url)
{
    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = CreateEndpoint(url);
    var channelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IMyService>(endpoint);
    InjectResolver(channelFactory.Endpoint);
    return channelFactory.CreateChannel();
}

private void InjectResolver(ServiceEndpoint endpoint)
{
    foreach (OperationDescription operation in endpoint.Contract.Operations)
    {
        var behavior = operation.Behaviors.Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();
        behavior.DataContractResolver = new DerivedTypeResolver(); // behavior is null here!
    }
}
```

Why is the behavior missing?

**UPDATE**: I found out the real issue is that WCF was using XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer. Is there a way to force a DataContractSerializer instead? Does WCF choose the serializer based on the wsdl? Considering I don't (yet) have the capacity to change the server side, what is my option? XmlSerializer behavior doesn't seem to have a similar option of resolving the type myself.

Answer (score 2):

See here for example on how to create DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior if it does not exist:

```
private void DataContractBehavior()
{
    WSHttpBinding b = new WSHttpBinding(SecurityMode.Message);
    Uri baseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:1066/calculator");
    ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(Calculator), baseAddress);
    sh.AddServiceEndpoint(typeof(ICalculator), b, "");

    // Find the ContractDescription of the operation to find.
    ContractDescription cd = sh.Description.Endpoints[0].Contract;
    OperationDescription myOperationDescription = cd.Operations.Find("Add");

    // Find the serializer behavior.
    DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior serializerBehavior =
        myOperationDescription.Behaviors.
           Find<DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior>();

    // If the serializer is not found, create one and add it.
    if (serializerBehavior == null)
    {
        serializerBehavior = new DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior(myOperationDescription);
        myOperationDescription.Behaviors.Add(serializerBehavior);
    }

    // Change the settings of the behavior.
    serializerBehavior.MaxItemsInObjectGraph = 10000;
    serializerBehavior.IgnoreExtensionDataObject = true;

    sh.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Listening");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

example from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.description.datacontractserializeroperationbehavior.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the example. I tried to add it myself also but I found out that the real issue was that WCF was using XmlSerializer instead of DataContractSerializer - that's probably why the behavior wasn't found.

Comment: This can help you http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/